# android - open activity after countdown

Tags: java, android

In my new game you have to press a button to get points. The player has to press the button within 5 seconds - if it takes more time, the GameOverScreen will be opened. Otherwise the countdown should restart. I tried to put the `gameover();` method in the `finish()` method of the countdown, but it seems possible that the finish method is always started and won't be cancelled. How can I stop the countdown to do that?

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity {
    public int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        Button count = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tvscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

        timer();
    }

    public void gameover() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameOverScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onClick (View view) {
        score++;
        tvscore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        timer();
    }

    public void timer(){
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%03d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))
                        ));
                if(animationRunning) {
                    cancel();
                }
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                text.setText("Too slow.");
                gameover();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: try calling cancel method for your countdown timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Simple and sophisticated way to achieve what you want.

Define a object of CountDownTimer at global level

```
CountDownTimer  mCountDownTimer  ;
```

Inside your onCreateView:

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%03d",
           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
           TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished));           
           }

         @Override
         public void onFinish() {
            text.setText("Too slow.");
            gameover();  
         }
     };
 mCountDownTimer.start();
```

In onClick()

```
  public void onClick (View view) 
    {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        score++;
        tvscore.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        mCountDownTimer.start();

    }
```

Comment: Just to understand: is it canceling the timer in some way or how does it help me with my problem?

Comment: calling mCountDownTimer.cancel(); will cancel the timer so, onFinished() wont be called.

Answer (score 0):

update your timer code like this:

```
private boolean isTimerCanceled = false;

public void timer(){ 
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 10) { 
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%03d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))
                        ));                     
                if(animationRunning) 
                {  
                    isTimerCanceled  = true;
                    cancel();
                } else{
                   isTimerCanceled = false;
                }             
            }
            public void onFinish() 
            {
                if (!isTimerCanceled){
                text.setText("Too slow.");  
                gameover();    
               }
            }
         }.start();    
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. After the five seconds it starts the `gameover` method anyway

Comment: Can be achieved without maintaining the flag.